# Remove first white space in Java

Tags: java

How would I remove the first white-space in Java?

Right now I am using this:

```
if (str.charAt(0) == ' ') str = str.replace(" ", "");
```

Comment: `replace( first, second )` replaces every instance of `first` with `second`.

Comment: This is not a matter of language rather a matter of libraries.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just use [`str.trim()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) to get rid of all leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: If this solves the _actual_ problem, the question and title should be edited.  The way the question reads, this answer is **NOT** correct.

Comment: Yes, it does solve the actual problem. The first white-space is removed with my solution. The OP did not say **only** the first white-space.

Comment: @syb0rg: In his original question, he said exactly that. His current solution removed all occurences, he wanted only the first. I am impressed that you managed to answer his actual question when he asked a different one.

Comment: @Keppil Looking at the editing revisions, I never saw the OP state only the first white-space.

Answer (score 14):

Use [`replaceFirst()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) instead of `replace()`.

TO get rid of all leading spaces you can use

```
str = str.replaceFirst("^ *", "");
```

The `^` is just to make sure that the spaces are actually at the start of the string, which it seems like you wanted. If that is not the case, just remove it.

Comment: It works, thanks. Can I remove all of the white spaces, just on the first of the String?

Comment: @Khan That will only remove the first space.  See my answer to remove all the leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: The OP says nothing about removing leading and trailing spaces.  This answer is correct (according to the title and question in their current state).

Answer (score 3):

You can use trim()

```
newString = stringToTrim.trim();
```

That will trim both sides of the string... beginning and end.. not sure if that helps.

More info here...  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

Comment: @syb0rg better late than never.. sorry took the extra minute to refer him to the API for a more complete answer.....

Comment: The real enemy is the useless answer sitting at 6 upvotes, stop fighting :P

Comment: @Esailija agreed.. Sorry all.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the answer by Keppil.  The OP says specifically that he wants to remove **only the first space**.  The way the question is asked, it suggests that he might only want to remove the first whitespace character **IF** it's the first character in the string.  He never says anything about multiple whitespace characters **OR** trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [String.substring()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29).

Invoking `s.substring(1)` will return everything but the first character the string `s`.

This works for your specific question, because you only want to remove the first character if it's a space.

```
if (str.charAt(0) == ' ') {
     str = str.substring(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want just the first or first and last?

[`trim()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) will remove what you want from the beginning and end of string. Otherwise Keppil's answer works.

Comment: Thank you. I just want to remove all the whitespaces on the first!

Comment: I think that even tail() is useful ; how can I use it?

Comment: I didn't find any documentation about `tail()`. The link you refer to is for `trim()`.

Comment: Woop, I mistyped the name, but the link should have wored as well.

Answer (score -1):

You could implement the `Character.isWhitespace` method into your code.

Link Here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa989424(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score -1):

```
  int charStartPos = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
     Char character = text.charAt(i);
     if (character == ' ' || character == '\t' || character == '\n') {
        charStartPos = i + 1;
     } else {
        break;
     }
  }
  text = text.substring(charStartPos);
```