# How remove space only first two word in String

Tags: java, android, removing-whitespace

I'm new in java and android I want to know how to remove space between two words in the string for example:

I have string `bookname="1 Samuel chapter 1 verse 1"`

**Expected Output**

book name: `"1samuel  chapter 1 verse 1"`

I want to remove space between the first two words.

Comment: If you're expecting somebody to write the code for you, we don't do that here sorry! First, have a look at this - [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You could try something like `replaceFirst()` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15558666/10576762).

Comment: @skyworld when you already know what actually my point then why you told me read how to ask ?And number of people here write code

Comment: use `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(inputString);` which have the `deleteCharAt(1)` method .

Comment: You could filter the words using a `regex` and then rebuild it concatenating the first and second match together without spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String a="t Shirt";
    a=a.replaceFirst(" ","");
    System.out.println(a);
```